# Dotnet Nuke IIS Configuration issue in Website

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, dotnetnuke

I am Configuring my DNN (6.0) Application in IIS 7.

A) I have go through the Add New Website and configure the application pool and etc. 
now, My application is running on Sites -> TestDNN.

Now, Problem is that Now 
B) I want to create my Application on Sites -> Default Website -> TestDNN.

I have tried to create TestDNN virtual directory and Convert it to application. I have match my all settings with the A) But it doesn't working and showing 404.0 Error on the page.

I have already added url in database in PortalAlias Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your question is:

1. You have a dnn instance runinig in IIS as a web site (Example http://abc.com:12345)
2. You want to re-use the same instance to be accessible from http://abc.com/testdnn/

Here is how you can do that.

1. Since you already have a running instance at http://abc.com:12345, login as host to that site.
2. Go to host > portals ( in 6.x Host > Site Management or something)
3. Select the defualt portal
4. Add new alias http://abc.com/testdnn/
5. Create a new virtual directory testdnn under localhost site and point it to same location as you pointed http://abc.com:12345
6. Make sure app pool for default website is using asp.net 4.0
7. Reset IIS
8. Try accessing your site from browser: http://abc.com/testdnn/default.aspx

Most probably if you are doing all above steps and you get the permissions proper like @condemypantsoff mentioned above, you will get it running without problem.

let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure that security is correct on the directory and you have pass through authentication set up correctly.

Comment: I have checked my authentication and security It is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel >> Programs And Features >> Turn Windows features on or off

Then go to  Internet Information Services >> World Wide Web Services >> Application Development Features

After that check ASP.net box and click OK.